# Convert datetime string where month is written with 3 digits

Tags: python, pandas

I can read/convert datetime string like

```
2004 06 01 00 01 37 600
```

with

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test.dat', widths=[25])
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.ix[:,0], format='%Y %m %d %H %M %S %f')
print dates
```

which prints

```
2004-06-01 00:01:37.600
```

But data I have actually uses 3 digits to present the month, like:

```
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600
```

How do I read/convert that?

There no mention for 3 digits month at http://strftime.org/.

I'm playing with data from http://www-ssc.igpp.ucla.edu/forms/polar/ascii_low.html (god knows why they use 3 digits to represent month).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the date format.

```
pd.to_datetime('2004 006 01 00 01 37 600', format='%Y 0%m %d %H %M %S %f')
# returns: Timestamp('2004-06-01 00:01:37.600000')
```